# GetBitmap() not working in release mode

Tags: visual-c++, bitmap, mfc

I am Working in MFC application. I have to get Height and Width of a BITMAP image. Code I'm using is working in Debug mode only but because of some problem I have to use release mode and in Release mode code is not working.help me out..!!!

```
    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.LoadBitmap(IDB_BITMAP1);
    BITMAP bm;
    bmp.GetBitmap(&bm);
```

Comment: Show some more code, I don't see an error here. Also in this code snipped you don't get the Width and Height. You will have to use the class CSize.

Comment: @Blacktempel, error is not there, its working in debug mode but not in release mode.

Comment: Where do you use this code ? In which function ? I have similar code too. Mine works in both release and debug..

Comment: I used that code in OnInitDialog()

Comment: Could you please show some more code ? As I this can't be all of your bitmap draw.

Comment: This is start code man, I Checked it line by line but its not working.

Comment: Err, wait, you use a local variable `CBitmap bmp;` to draw a Bitmap ? This WILL fail. Use it as member variable. Haven't seen it until now sorry.

Comment: 1. You can debug in release mode too! 2. What do you mean with "doesn't work" what is the return code of GetBitmap?

Comment: It is returning some value like this

        bm = {bmType=117 bmWidth=39 bmHeight=468 ...}
Actually my image width is 117, which is going in bmType, and image height is 39 which is going to bmWidth.

Answer (score 0):

```
CBitmap bmp;
```

Don't use a local variable to draw a bitmap. It will be gone after the function has been called.

Use a member variable.
For instance:

```
m_Background.LoadBitmap (IDB_BITMAP1);
BITMAP bm;
m_Background.GetBitmap (&bm);
m_BitmapSize = CSize (bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight);
Invalidate(1);
```